# WPF + Windows Forms Error Handling

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, error-handling, exception

I have a project wich had been made in Windows Forms, so I have to migrate it gradually to WPF; I've copied all my forms/classes into a new WPF project.
Everything runs just fine, but whenever I try to catch an exception that has been generated from [Windows Forms] forms, the `DispatcherUnhandledException` event just don't catch it.

What should I do to catch all exceptions from [Windows Forms] forms into `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` event?

**Edit 1:** 
I'm using application events to handle `DispatcherUnhandledException`
If I put a breakpoint on the event code, it just doesn't step by.
The way I'm handling the exceptions is the same as all my WPF applications, then only thing that makes this project different it's the inclussion of [Windows Forms] forms.


***When I throw exception from a WPF window it works perfectly, but when I do it on [Windows Forms] form doesn't works.***

Thanks in advice.

Comment: How do you handle that Application.DispatcherUnhandledException? You may take a look at MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx

Comment: through application events

Comment: You could try to use an automated handler if you would like https://github.com/gauffininteractive/onetrueerror.server

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd. If your using MVVM then all your app errors are in your ViewModel and easy to capture with a try..catch. If not MVVVM just add try catch to each method in your code-behind class.

Comment: The weirdest thing it's that I got the same code for catching exception in the Windows Forms project but seems that WPF + Windows Forms works different.